# Set Drupal Rabbit-hole settings programmatically

Tags: drupal-9

Is it possible to update [Drupal Rabbit-Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) values for a node programmatically?

```
function my_hook_cron() {
  $some_rh_service->update_rh($my_node, 'content_not_found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There maybe be a better way, but the following works:

```
$node->set('rh_action', 'page_not_found');
$node->set('rh_redirect_response', 301);
```